# Finding out the length between two points

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

I have following diagram with these values:

[image: Pic 1]

How can I determine the length of OD and BD?

Comment: Observe that triangles $ADO$ and $BDC$ are similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$BD:BC=OD:OA$ and $BD+OD=4$ are two linear equations. The solution is $BD=5/2$ and $OD=3/2$.